# How to setup a local single node Docker Swarm on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm on a Ubuntu machine and I'm trying to setup a local environment to test my docker stacks, I've created a Swarm using `docker swarm init` and also `docker swarm init --advertise-adr <IP>` with some IPs I've found while running `ifconfig`.

The swarm is initialized and everything looks fine, but when I deploy a stack on it I can't access my services using a browser, it just remains loading forever.

I've tried the same stack on an AWS environment and it worked, so I am assuming is something related with my current local environment.

Also if I run the same stack with `docker-compose up` it works.

`iptables -S` output:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-INGRESS
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-INGRESS
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-7c734e310943 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-7c734e310943 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-7c734e310943 ! -o br-7c734e310943 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-7c734e310943 -o br-7c734e310943 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge ! -o docker_gwbridge -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -
-sport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i br-7c734e310943 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker0 -o br-7c734e310943 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker_gwbridge -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker0 -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker_gwbridge -o br-7c734e310943 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i br-7c734e310943 -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

Comment: The commands as you've described them could be correct, or at the very least there's nothing there to describe what you are doing wrong. Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with any errors you are seeing in journalctl.

Comment: Is ufw enabled by any chance?

Comment: Not enabled @TarunLalwani :(

Comment: So the main host itself is ubuntu? no VMs involved? Also can you add output of `iptables -S` from the machine to your question after the service is up? Use pastebin if log is too large

Comment: No VMs involved @TarunLalwani, also, I am adding the command output you requested to the question

Comment: Okie does `docker run -p 80:80 nginx` work ? Let's isolate if it is swarm or docker itself?

Comment: I think you found something, after entering the above command to run nginx and expose port 80 the console window won't respond at all, it just freezes